# How to generate basic reports in Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, report

I need to show reports if user click the button. I can able to add Labels and Tables but how to bind data to that tables ? I have form in that some text fields and Gridview is available. Now I need to show that gridview to table and text fields to label in gridview ? Please give idea to complete my task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using XtraReports?

Comment: Hi Steve, yes am using XtraReports

Comment: Here a link to the DevExpress site that could help you in binding your data to the report http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Steve Finally created different reports using this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Create a report. 
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

    // Show the report's preview. 
    ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);

    tool.ShowPreview();
}
```